# Cutting and fading ts segment with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to cut a ts segment and apply a fade from white at the initial point of the *cut* segment. This is used in a situation where I need to "crop" some material from the beginning of a video and apply a fade for a smoother entry. In my test, I am cutting an 8 second segment at the 5.5s mark to yield a 2.5 second segment that will fade from white over the first second.

The cut command by itself works fine:

```
ffmpeg  -i test.ts  -ss 5.5 -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -c:a aac -map 0 -mpegts_copyts 1  -preset ultrafast -f ssegment -initial_offset 5.5 -segment_format mpegts   ~/Desktop/cut%d.ts
```

I've successfully used this fade filter syntax before:

```
-filter:v fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:color=0xffffff
```

But I can't seem to make the whole thing work:

```
ffmpeg  -i test.ts  -filter:v fade=t=in:st=5.5:d=1:color=0xffffff  -ss 5.5 -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -c:a aac -map 0 -mpegts_copyts 1  -preset ultrafast -f ssegment -initial_offset 5.5 -segment_format mpegts   ~/Desktop/cut%d.ts
```

I'm getting the following error:

x264 [error]: baseline profile doesn't support 4:4:4

[libx264 @ 0x7fd9db002400] Error setting profile baseline.

[libx264 @ 0x7fd9db002400] Possible profiles: baseline main high high10 
high422 high444

Error initializing output stream 0:1 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

[aac @ 0x7fd9db001200] Qavg: nan

Conversion failed!

My knowledge of ffmpeg just isn't deep enough to figure out why this is happening. Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Okay I put loglevel to debug and saw some problems related to the baseline profile. This revised command seems to work: 

`ffmpeg  -i test.ts  -filter:v fade=t=in:st=5.5:d=1:color=0xffffff  -ss 5.5 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -map 0 -mpegts_copyts 1  -preset ultrafast -f ssegment -initial_offset 5.5 -segment_format mpegts   ~/Desktop/cut%d.ts`

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of `-profile:v baseline` will 'solve' it but the resulting video won't be playable in many players since ffmpeg will have autoselected profile `high444` for you.

Instead, use

```
ffmpeg -i test.ts
-vf fade=t=in:st=5.5:d=1:color=0xffffff,format=yuv420p
-ss 5.5 -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -c:a aac -map 0 -preset ultrafast
-mpegts_copyts 1 -f ssegment -initial_offset 5.5 -segment_format mpegts ~/Desktop/cut%d.ts
```

Baseline profile only supports YUV 4:2:0 planar pixel format.

Comment: This works. My original command worked in the player I use (clappr) but I'm not sure it looked right. Thanks for the tip!!